# Issue with GHUnit Testing for iPhone

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

I am working on Unit Test using third party framework GHUnit, created project added GHUnit framework and other framework which are needed. 
I created one class called TestCases, in that import library GHUnit and class which need to write test case.

I need to write test cases for 40 classes.
Do i need to write all test cases in one single class.

Do i need to create each class for testCase?
If Yes then when i try to create new class in separate testCase1,testCase2....testCase40 it can't able to show those testCases1 testCase2 ...testCase40

IT shows me a tableview and run button and only first testCases methods, its not showing me remaining testCases Class method. 
Please advice in this situation. What action i need to do for this

@Advance thanks you all.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate unit testing (functionality testing) integration testing (complete system working testing)

UNIT TESTING: **(for each of those 40 classes)**
Usually write different test class for each of the class, so that if there is a single change in any of the class can test it by specifically running that particular class, so if there is one or 40 or 100s of class better write unit test for each of them and ensure there functionality.

In each class better write different test cases for testing different functionality, so that it will be easy to identity (for a third person, not the one who develop it and written test case for that) where the error come from, and manage them.

Each function better test only one case, write different test cases for testing different functional behavior of each functions. So it may result with 100 test cases in a single class for testing a class with 10 functions. But it is good.

INTEGRATION TESTING: **(for testing depended functionality of 40 classes)**
When come to integration testing, write test cases for different behavior of complete system, in a single class with different possibilities (test cases).

And finally **“Spend more time for testing than coding”**.
Also ensure the coverage of test cases for the code is between 90% to 100%.